# CSS Transition working one way but not the other, not sure why

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-transitions

I have been working on something based on brad frost's Off Canvas Fullscreen Overlay responsive design pattern.

However for some reason the transition only runs when clicking on the list item (the overlay slides in from the right) but not when you then click on the back button (it is suppose to slide back out). I can't understand why it isn't working when a user closes the overlay. The JS that effects the class of the elements seems to be working correctly.

I've created a codepen so people can see what is happening. http://codepen.io/colmjude/pen/fBnrI

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is your demo supposed to do? I don't see any way to interact.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. The browser window needs to be less than 600px for it to kick in. Then click the single list item and a panel with text in should slide in. That bit works fine but when you close the text panel it just closes rather than sliding back out and I can't fathom why.